# Seleccionar todos los inputs cuyo atributo name sea diferente a una palabra en específico

Tags: jquery, css

Tengo una página web con muchas etiquetas `inputs`, algunas de ellas tienen
en su atributo `name` diferentes valores y algunos de esos valores comienzan con la palabara "especial" (sin comillas), por ejemplo:

`<input value="0" type="text" name="especial0modeloSaco#52102">`

Necesito crear un selector en jQuery que seleccione todos los `inputs` que en su atributo `name` no comiencen con la palabra "especial" (sin comillas), intenté con esto:

`$('not:input[name^=especial]')`

Pero no funcionó.

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo hacerlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando solo un selector, puedes hacerlo así:

```js
const elemento = $('input:not([name^=especial])');

console.log(elemento.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="especial" type="text" name="especial0modeloSaco#52102">
<input value="no es especial" type="text" name="otracosa">
```

`:not()` es una pseudo clase que toma otro selector como argumento

Comment: Esta me gusta más, es más simple y utiliza pseudo clases de jQuery. Gracias por la respuesta @Emeeus

Answer (score 3):

puedes hacerlo con el metodo [not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) de `jquery` ejemplo:

```js
notSpecial  = $('input').not("[name^=especial]");
 
console.log(notSpecial.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="0" type="text" name="especial0modeloSaco#52102">

<input value="0" type="text" name="especial0modeloSaco#52103">

<input value="0" type="text" name="especial0modeloSaco#52104">
<input value="0" type="text" name="especial0modeloSaco#52105">
<input value="0" type="text" name="especial0modeloSaco#52106">
<input value="0" type="text" name="superespecial0modeloSaco#52106">
<input value="0" type="text" name="superespecial0modeloSaco#52107">
```